# Nav menu indicator - sliding on hover, on click, and on scroll

Tags: javascript

I've never asked a question here, but I've made use of many answers so am hoping that the effect I'm hoping to achieve will also help others looking to achieve the same effect.

I'm currently working on a client's website and have uploaded it to my dropbox for this question: 
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62164771/stage/cw/index16042013.html

It currently uses a few different scripts to achieve the following:

(this script is in the head area)
The navigation menu is fixed, and when you click on a menu link, the page scrolls to the relevant section.
When the page scrolls to the relevant section (after being clicked on), a class (.act) is added to the active menu link. The .act class is also added when the user scrolls up and down in the page with their mouse/track pad or whatever.

(this script is at the bottom of the page)
Another effect is also added to the nav bar links: 
When you hover over a nav item, a nav menu indicator arrow (a div with a background image of an arrow) slides across to the hovered link.

**So this is what I want to happen**

Currently the nav menu indicator arrow only slides on hover. I want it to slide to the active link when it is clicked and stay there until the user hovers on another link. My current script is a little buggy with the menu indicator not always sliding to the active link.

I also want the nav menu indicator arrow to slide to the active link when the user scrolls through the page.

Is this achievable?

**Relevant Scripts**

**Script 1 - scroll smoothly to section and activate 'act' class when scrolling:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    $('nav a').on('click', function() {
      var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
      scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]')
        .offset().top + 1;
      $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
      }, 500);
      return false;
    })

    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (windscroll >= 100) {
        $('#wrap section').each(function(i) {
          if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 200) {
            $('nav a.act').removeClass('act');
            $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('act');
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        $('nav a.act').removeClass('act');
        $('nav a:first').addClass('act');
      }

    }).scroll();
  })
</script>
```

**Script 2 - For sliding the main-menu-indicator to the position of the hovered and active links**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#header')
  .css('position', 'relative')
  .append(
    $('<div>').attr('id', 'main-menu-indicator')
  )
  menuHover = function(which){

    if(which==null)
      which = $('ul#main-menu a.act')
    $('#main-menu-indicator')
      .stop(true, false)
      .animate({
        left: ($(which).offset().left - $('#header').offset().left +
          $(which).width()/2 + parseInt($(which).css('paddingLeft')) -
          $('#main-menu-indicator').width()/2 )
      }, 500)
  } 

$('ul#main-menu a')
  .hover(
    function(){
      menuHover(this)
    },
    function(){
      menuHover(null)
    }
  ) 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Bootstrap ScrollSpy](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#scrollspy) to get the desired effect, it might be easier to implement than writing your own solution. You could start the animation using the `activate` event.

In your case you could set `<a href="#top">`, you currently have a `section` and an `article` with the same `id`, you should get rid of one of those as it is invalid html to have more than one element with the same `id`, and it might break things. For example keep the `id` on the `article`: `<article class="top area" id="top">`. Include the ScrollSpy script on the page and add:

```
$('.header').scrollspy({activate: function() {
  // Add your logic here.
  }
});
```

Inside the activate function `$('nav li.active')` will give you the currently active `li`, with that info you should be able to work out where to move your arrow, and you can then run your smooth scrolling arrow code to move the arrow to the right place.

Now ScrollSpy takes care of calling `activate` when the user scrolls somewhere, and you react on that by moving the arrow to the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I don't see how I could achieve the sliding arrow part of the problem with it. Unless I'm just not getting something?

Comment: I have edited the answer to show you how I think it would work.

Comment: I'm way out of my depth here on the code - the code above are snippets I've found and customised. Writing the code for this is above my current ability.
Another way I thought of tackling this is for the menu indicator arrow to follow the link with the class .act, and then that way when the page scroll code activates the .act class the arrow follows it. then all i'd need is to have the .act class get added to the hovered link, and the arrow would follow it on hover, on click, and on scroll. 
the problem is I can't figure out how to do it.